# VB - DataGrid em TextBoxes

Tags: vb.net

Boas.

Tenho a PAP para fazer e gostaria que me ajudassem, por favor.

Tenho o seguinte form:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que ao clicar na lupa ao lado do "adicionar" me vai redirecionar para outro form que me lista todos os dados adicionados na base de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ate aqui tudo bem...

Mas depois... ao clicar, nas cells da coluna, so ao clicar na do nome é que funciona e não é totalmente eficiente. para isso.. pensei em selecionar a linha e em clicar no botao "visualizar" as linhas seleccionadas aparecerem individualmente. Alguem sabe como o fazer?

Agradeço desde ja a vossa atenção, obrigado.

Comment: a linha selecionada iria aparecer onde exatamente ?

Comment: Iria responder nas textboxes do form "Empregados" como mostra o exemplo

Comment: Entendi, você tem uma classe para cada empregado?

Comment: poste a parte do código em que preenche a tela Empregados por faovr